# Input text conditional statement Flash cs6

Tags: flash

hello goodevening to all of you guys i will be straight now. im sorry for my english cause its not my first language. im making a identification quiz game . where if the user type the correct answer the score will increase by 1. if not the score will stay 0. i have a code here but its not working, idk why, i think this is really right . the problem is whatever i will input the score will be 0 and when i use OR statement , everthing i input will be correct. pls help me this is for my thesis thanks

```
stop();
var score:int = 0;



if(answer1.text == "Africa")
{
score = score +1
}
```

Code for second frame

```
Scoretext2.text = score.toString();
```

And thats all my test code

And if i try this code . Everything ill put is correct and my score will increase

```
If (answer1.text =  "africa" || “Africa” || “AFRICA” )
{
score = score + 1
}
```

Comment: and hey guys this is my second layer code for the scoring

Comment: stop();
scoretext2.text = score.toString();

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things...

```
if (answer1.text =  "africa" || “Africa” || “AFRICA” )
{
    score = score + 1
}
```

Check equality with the == operator, not a single =, like so:

```
if(answer1.text == "africa")
```

Use the OR operator for each condition you would like to check, like so:

```
if(answer1.text == "africa" || answer1.text == "Africa" || answer1.text == "AFRICA")
```

but, all of these OR operators are not necessary. Do this:

```
var answer:String = answer1.text.toLowerCase();
if(answer == "africa") score++;
```

Comment: hey, i try it but whats happening now is the score is not displaying , i dont know what happen. im sorry im new here

Comment: maybe it's supposed to be

    score.text = int(score.text) + 1;

Comment: if(answer == "africa") score.text = int(score.text) + 1;

Comment: hello again, the codes u gave me is not working, so i changed it to score = int(score) +1; and it work but still the score is increasing. im sorry for the trouble and i appreciate your help

Comment: Btw im making an air for android